# Can a pan gesture be used for moving UIWindows?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

Is it possible to move a `UIWindow` via a pan gesture recognizer? I've been having issues understanding how the gestures works and have managed to get it working for views but not windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

`UIWindow` is subclass of `UIView` and you can add `PanGesture` normally. To move window, change frame of `UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window`, it will work fine.

Create a new project and replace `AppDelegate.m` file with my code below. You can move window.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGesture;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastPoint;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  self.panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
  [self.window addGestureRecognizer:_panGesture];
  _needUpdate = YES;

  return YES;
}

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture {
  CGPoint point = [panGesture locationInView:self.window];
  CGPoint center = self.window.center;

  if (CGPointEqualToPoint(_lastPoint, CGPointZero)) {
    _lastPoint = point;
  }

  center.x += point.x - _lastPoint.x;
  center.y += point.y - _lastPoint.y;
  self.window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
  self.window.center = center;

  if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    _lastPoint = CGPointZero;
  }
}


@end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This got it partially working. But it's jumping between the start point and new point.  Andy idea why? It's as if it's tryi to set it to both

Comment: @KaneBuckthorpe I have updated answer. You can check again. Please let me know if it works ;)

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you! This had been troubling me for ages hahaa